# Spring Boot 3 / Hibernate 6 / PostgresSql ENUM Mapping Issue

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, psql

I'm upgrading to spring boot 3 and updating from MySql to Postgres at the same time (I'm aware I probably should do one at a time) and I'm running into issues with my ENUMS.
Worth noting the enums are custom types in the Postgres example below;

```
CREATE TYPE calc_sales_status_enum AS ENUM (
    'NoUse',
    'InUse',
    'Vulnerable',
    'PartiallyVulnerable',
    'PartialUse'
);
```

Then I'm setting each ENUM up like follows

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@GenericField(sortable = Sortable.YES)
var calcSalesStatus: SalesStatus? = null
```

Which compiles completely fine, however when I come to run a hibernate query (insert/update/fetch) I get an error message detailing that it can't be mapped

```
17:05:02.177 [main] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42804
17:05:02.177 [main] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: column "status" is of type status_enum but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 177
17:05:02.177 [main] INFO  o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl - HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

So to combat this I set the type using the recommended hypersistent utils library

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Type(PostgreSQLEnumType::class)
@GenericField(sortable = Sortable.YES)
var calcSalesStatus: SalesStatus? = null
```

Now all of my tests work as expected and getting 100% succefull tests, however when I got to run the application locally I get the following errors

```
17:23:36.157 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291)
    at io.novaware.abinbev.ABInBevApplicationKt.main(ABInBevApplication.kt:59)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "<local3>" is null
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.getAnnotation(EnumType.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.getEnumType(EnumType.java:229)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.setParameterValues(EnumType.java:137)
    at io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.basic.PostgreSQLEnumType.setParameterValues(PostgreSQLEnumType.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.MappingHelper.injectParameters(MappingHelper.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeDefinition.createResolution(TypeDefinition.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.TypeDefinition.createLocalResolution(TypeDefinition.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.interpretExplicitlyNamedType(BasicValue.java:681)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$4(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1767)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1682)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1660)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1766)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1752)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.buildMetadataInstance(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:2292)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1350)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1421)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Have you got an ideas as to what could be the issue?

Extra Help:
I'm using Kotlin 1.8, java 17 and here is my dependency tree https://pastebin.com/9EUKVpGM

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this up in case anyone runs into this issue, the problem is within the libray hypersistence-utils, and a hibernate version higher than 6.1. Looks like it's not going to be fixed for a while. So having to set the specific enum name in the column field

https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils/issues/519

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependency hibernate core 6.3.1.Final or later

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then make change to your entity like this for mapping to postgresql enum

```
    @Column(name = "enum_name", columnDefinition = "enum_defination")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.NAMED_ENUM)
    private EnumType enumName;
```